# AngularJS not calling function on button click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJD to insert data into mongoose db. My index file has a div:

```
<div id="links" ng-controller="loginController">
    <a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
    <a ui-sref="register">Register</a>
</div>
```

I use routing to redirect to this page. On my registration page, I'm trying to call a function on the click event of a button:

```
<form ng-app="login" name="myForm" ng-submit="addNew()" novalidate>
   <p>
      <input type="submit"
          ng-disabled="myForm.lname.$dirty && myForm.lname.$invalid ||
          myForm.fname.$dirty && myForm.fname.$invalid ||
          myForm.mail.$dirty && myForm.mail.$invalid ||
          myForm.pwd.$dirty && myForm.pwd.$invalid ||
          myForm.cpwd.$dirty && myForm.cpwd.$invalid">
    </p>
</form>
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
function loginController($scope)
{
    console.log('inside');
    $scope.addNew = function()
    {
        console.log('adding new entry');
        var newuser = {
            username: $scope.NewUname,
            firstname: $scope.fName,
            lastname: $scope.lName,
            email: $scope.mail,
            $password: $scope.pwd
        }

    }
}
```

When I debug, it is logging "inside" but not "adding new entry".

Comment: I don't see an `ng-controller="loginController"` wrapping the form. Are you omitting it here only?

Comment: Not sure what your issue is either without full context.  Here is a working fiddle doing basically what you have:  http://jsfiddle.net/smaye81/qn2vdufn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're creating your `ng-app` on the form inside the `register.html` route template. The element that establishes the app with `ng-app="login"` should contain everything else. Thus your `loginController`, which would be instantiated via `ng-controller="loginController"`, is not actually created because it is outside the angular application.

### Edit

I just noticed that you said "inside" is logged, which actually means that the `loginController` *is* being instantiated. I'm guessing you've got another `ng-app` established in some other containing context around the `links` div. However, I still think your issue is that you're creating a new `ng-app` on the form itself in `register.html`. I'm pretty sure you can't nest an angular application inside another. Best case, this would be interrupting the `loginController` context inside the form (it's probably doing more/worse than that). One way or another I think that `ng-app` declaration is your problem.